# Want to insert multiple rows from a json file in amazon's dynamoDB

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to insert multiple rows of data to amazon's dynamoDB. I had tried the code on this page 
[this page of amazon php guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.PHP.02.html#GettingStarted.PHP.02.02)

But it is inserting data one by one in a for loop is there any way to insert it in one time or one call.

Because every time it inserts a row it calls the dynamoDB and this will lead to a performance issue if we have a thousand's of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link for php batch write on dynamodb.

```
$dynamodb->batchWriteItem
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPBatchOperationsExample.html

Comment: $response = $client->batchWriteItem([
    'RequestItems' => [
        'Movies' => [
            [
                'PutRequest' => [
                    'Item' => $marshaler->marshalJson($json)
                    ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);

Comment: when i run above code following error is produced : Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'The JSON document must be valid and be an object at its root.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\restApi\aws\Aws\DynamoDb\Marshaler.php:99 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\restApi\batchputItemByJSON.php(22): Aws\DynamoDb\Marshaler->marshalJson('[\n {\n ...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\restApi\aws\Aws\DynamoDb\Marshaler.php on line 99